# Update stats for ETL tables

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2019, enterprise-edition

There is a huge table with more than 2 tb size . Etl algorithm is as below,

1. if new scenario it will insert millions of data in partition table
   2)if old scenario it will reimport & delete older records .

Update stats with sample percent 20 taking more than 10 hrs conflicting other business jobs . Need a suitable scenario as how to schedule this update stats within shorter maintenance plan (5hrs). Not sure incremental stats can be possible as well

Comment: What database system, version, and edition?

Comment: It's in gcp cloud - SQL server 2019 enterprise.. I have disabled update stats everyday and scheduled it to run only on weekends . But I am afraid if any performance issues arises. Everyday millions of insert are occurring and the algorithm selects the newly inserted data for further processing

Comment: Have you tried reducing the sample percent? Why do you initially choose 20%?

Comment: Also how do you this is true: "*conflicting other business jobs*"?

Comment: Maintenance window time is very less & other jobs are been run parallel .choosen 20 percentage as to give some what accurate results of data distribution..

Comment: Look at sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats - what's your IOPS at during the stats rebuild, what's the io_stall (latency) at?  If IOPS is at, say, 480-520, you're probably limited to 500 IOPS or so on your VM, and that plus the size of the table is your core issue.

Comment: Thanks All. Luckily I have reviewed the modification counter value & since auto update stats is enabled it is doing stats update accordingly and no issues has been seen till now